# How can I set angular date picker date-format form a method of service in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

I want to set 'dateInput' dynamically form Auth service based on user type.
I use 'ServiceName.getMethod' and I tried to solve it by creating a class, but It doesn't solve.

```
 export class SchoolDateFormat {
    public schoolDateFormat = '';
    constructor(private auth: AuthenticationService) {
        if ( this.auth.isLoggedIn() ) {
            if ( this.auth.isSystemUser() ) {
                this.schoolDateFormat = this.auth.getCountryDateFormat();
            }else {
                this.schoolDateFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
            }
        }else {
            this.schoolDateFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
        }
    }
    get getDateFormat() {
        return this.schoolDateFormat;
    }
}

const schoolDate = new SchoolDateFormat([AuthenticationService]);

export const MY_FORMATS = {
        parse: {
            dateInput: 'YYYY-MM-D',
        },
        display: {
            dateInput: schoolDate.getDateFormat,
            monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
            dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
            monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
        },
    };
```

Comment: so you want to get the current date automatically? describe what you want and clear your question

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullah I add my own code. but it is not working.

Comment: You should probably rename the `getDateFormat` getter to `dateFormat`.

Comment: @Edric I had rename that, but I Can't create an object of SchoolDateFormat class. It has an error in [AuthenticationService] parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I Set this value in the Cookie and get data from the cookie to handle this problem.